# FeatureLines civil3d

Tags: lisp, autodesk

I'll try to make code in lisp that will create a feature line from pline.
Unfortunately the code stops at the feature line creation window.

```
(defun c:plineToSpline ()
  (setq ent (car (entsel "\nSelect a polyline: "))) ; Poprosi o wskazanie pline
  (command "_.pedit" ent "_s" "") ; Zamieni zaznaczony pline na spline
  (setq splineEnt (entlast)) ; Pobierz identyfikator ostatnio utworzonej spline
  (command "_.splinedit" splineEnt "_p" "0" "") ; Zaznaczy utworzoną spline
  (setq plineEnt (entlast))
  (command "AeccCreateFeatureLines" "_p" plineEnt "")
  (vl-cmdf "_.delay" "500" "") ; Delay to ensure dialog is open
  (vl-cmdf "_.key" "ENTER" "")
  (command "") ; Zamknie okno tworzenia FeatureLines
  (princ))
```

Comment: Please explain your main concern and issue in detail.

Comment: My code reaches the line (command "AeccCreateFeatureLines" "_p" plineEnt ""). At the end of the line there is a double quotation mark which in Lisp means enter. Unfortunately, the feature line creation window does not close, you just have to press the ok button. This does not allow the code to continue.